# Fuzzy match on a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, presto

I am looking to join two tables where there's a 90% match for example.

Taking the example below, I want to join table A and table B on the phone number. You can see that the phone numbers differ slightly (the international code). I'd like the end result to show as table C.

I imagine it'll be something like but the join would specify to match on 90% of the `phone_number`

```
select
a.*,
b.most_recent_booking_date
from a 
left join b
on a.phone_number = b.phone_number
```

Hope that's clear and any help would be great! Cheers!

Table A

| Phone number | Most recent call date |
| --- | --- |
| 441234567891 | 01/05/22 |
| 441234567892 | 02/05/22 |

Table B

| Phone number | Most recent booking date |
| --- | --- |
| +441234567891 | 03/05/22 |
| +441234567892 | 04/05/22 |

Table C

| Phone number | Most recent call date | Most recent bookingdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 441234567891 | 01/05/22 | 03/05/22 |
| 441234567892 | 02/05/22 | 04/05/22 |

Comment: Just remove `+` from both sides?

Comment: don't you have ID's on your tables? Primary/Foreign keys? your tables cant match right now as they are, cause   phone number from A can never match phone number from B , unless ofc you concate the string and add the extra + ...  but this is not the correct approach to do it. if you have Primary and foreight keys I suggest you use them. that is the point of relational databases

Comment: You can create a function to regex match the values and use OUTER APPLY to join the data. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175156(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175156(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: We can use REPLACE().

Comment: Normalization of the data is the real answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, but I don't like it, as Demeteor says you should have an ID to join on. Note that I use a left join here, in case there is no data in table #T2. I was also considering a computed column where it removes the + and then you could join that way too. I will also get told off for SQL injection if the phone number could be dodgy.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    CallDate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #T2 (
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    BookingDate DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #T1 (PhoneNumber, CallDate)
VALUES
('441234567891', '20220501'),
('441234567892', '20220502');


INSERT INTO #T2 (PhoneNumber, BookingDate)
VALUES
('+441234567891', '20220503'),
('+441234567892', '20220504');

GO

SELECT *
FROM #T1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN #T2 AS T2 ON T2.PhoneNumber LIKE '%' + T1.PhoneNumber;
```